# Latex PdF viewer swaps even and odd pages

Tags: pdf, viewers

I've just updated TeX and doing so seems to have introduced a weird quirk that happens when viewing a .pdf through the Tex PDF viewer. I have my Tex PDF viewer set to view 'Two pages' and after compiling a document, the PDF viewer shows Page 1 as a single page then for subsequent pages shows the next odd numbered page on the left and the even numbered page on the right, i.e. apart from page 1 which is on it's own it shows pairs of consecutive pages with the odd (higher numbered page) on the left and the previous even numbered page on the right, that is, they are backwards! This issue is not present when viewing the compiled PDF through a non-LTteX program.

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using? Does the problem happen with other viewers? It'd help to know whether the problem comes from the application or the PDF generation.

Comment: I don't think it's the PDF generation - I'm on a Mac and when I open the PDF with preview it labels the pages correctly. When the PDF is opened automatically after compiling/typesetting the TeX file, the issue occurs.

Comment: Complement to my previous comment: I was asking because your last sentence is unclear. Did you mean "non-LaTeX program"? Since LaTeX doesn't include any PDF viewer, you should mention which *distribution* and specific software you're using.

Comment: This is a behavior that is the default in several PDF viewers. It mimics the look of the real, printed book (where the even page is on the left, and the first page - the title page - is alone). The viewer probably has an option to switch it off, but IMHO what you see is the logical thing to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like either version 4.75 or 4.76 of TeXShop. If you have 4.75 update to 4.76. Then read the Help->Changes document for an explanation of the changes to preview page handling in Double Page Views. You will have to change the Double Page Modes section on the Preview tab in TeXShop->Preferences. The wording and meaning have changed to better represent what they now mean.